# macOs vscode how to update the include path

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang

I am using vs code on macOs and I have this error.
[image]

I searched all the solution. It points me to configure the include path.
I tried to use below code in the terminal

```
clang++ -v -xc++ -
```

to get where the include search start.And I got this information.[image]

So I include `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include` into the configuration json like below.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

But vscode tells me that it cannot find this path. Is there anything that I did wrong? How can I fix the includePath error on macOS?

Comment: `"${/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include}/**"` get rid of the `${` and `}` in the previous line `${workspaceFolder}` these symbols are used because `workspaceFolder` is a variable.